How to load base64 images into react-pdf?
I'm trying to get base64 images in a variety of formats (gif, png, jpg) to show in react-pdf.
{c.images.map((d) => {
const prefix = 'data:image/' + d.filename.split('.').pop() + ';base64,'
return <Image src={prefix + d.fileInBase64}  />
})}


This is in <PDFDownloadLink>, not sure if that matters.
If I change react-pdf's  to a JSX  tag and use the code above, the images appear in react. But in react-pdf, it's just blank. The pdf loads, but with no images, and vitally, no error messages.

There should be no problem using Base64 images using standard HTML syntax src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA.....="(ensure that string is URL safe) in react-PDF-Renderer. Here I took the demo image reversing colours direction and quality and it still works. This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75971365/10802527
So easiest way to test functionality without owning reactjs is try https://react-pdf.org/repl

However the Demo itself was known to have a problem with JPEG images that still seems to be there in the online demo version. And unknown if it also affects some other image loading. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78080910/10802527

